# What is the equivalent parser for TouchXML in Android?

Tags: iphone, android, xml-parsing

In my iPhone project I was using the TouchXML parser. I want to develop that project in Android. I am new to Android, can anyone suggest a parser I should use. I just need to read XML and have no need of writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android comes with all standard Java XML parsers (except some exotic XPath in <2.2 IIRC). So you can learn standard Java XML parsing techniques and should be good to go.

Also take a look here:

1. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/package-summary.html
2. http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/package-summary.html

You need to watch closely which Android version provides which XML parsers & classes. We ended up including a custom .jar file to support certain operations.

Comment: there is also a soap response

Comment: @xydev you mean the XML you like to parse is SOAP?